# xerces: how to take xml node with a particular tag?

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

with Qt library I can take a node with a particular tag name with:

```
QDomElement tmp = root.firstChildElement("A");
QDomElement tt = tmp.firstChildElement("C");
```

with a xml file with this structure:

```
<A>
<B></B>
<C></C>
</A>
```

With xerces, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMElement.html)? getElementByTagName is the primary method you need.

Comment: Ok but from DOMNodeList (obtained by getElementByTagName()), how can I take a particular tag element?

Comment: [Documentation](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNodeList.html) again, use the item method and maybe the getLength method to check that you actually found the node you are looking for.

Comment: Here an example of use:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/XML-Xerces-C.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
// create the DOM parser
xercesc_3_2::XercesDOMParser* parser = new xercesc_3_2::XercesDOMParser;
parser->setValidationScheme(xercesc_3_2::XercesDOMParser::Val_Never);
parser->parse(fileName.c_str());
// get the DOM representation
xercesc_3_2::DOMDocument* doc = parser->getDocument();
// get the root element
xercesc_3_2::DOMElement* root = doc->getDocumentElement();

// evaluate the xpath
xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult* result = doc->evaluate(
    xercesc_3_2::XMLString::transcode("/doc/document/childL1/childL2/Node_to_change"), // "A/B" in the provided xml sample for change B text node value
    root,
    NULL,
    xercesc_3_2::DOMXPathResult::ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    NULL);
```

And also change the value:

```
if (result->getNodeValue() == NULL)
{
    cout << "There is no result for the provided XPath " << endl;
}
else
{

    result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->setNodeValue(xercesc_3_2::XMLString::transcode("3000"));
    const XMLCh* a = result->getNodeValue()->getFirstChild()->getNodeValue();
    char* tttt = (char*)a;
    cout << "Node value: " << tttt << endl;
    
}
```